# MVC Why unit test controllers

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, controller

just a Provocative Question

why do you thing we should unit test controllers in MVC why not just write test against models or service layer.

Comment: That's usually what the unit testing reveals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example should be this one (in BDD-style):

Given the user 'snehal' does not exists
When I create a new user with credentials 'snehal' and 'so@123'
And I log in with this user
Then I should see a welcome page

This scenario is expecting that new user should see a welcome page when they log in for the first time. At least for me, this is the Controller's job and is a nice feature that I would like to make sure it is works.

Comment: even i feel all the requirements should be captured as unit test on controllers. Is their any good book/resources for this?

Answer (score 1):

One point is testing your routes.

Answer (score 1):

The controllers can contain quite a bit of critical functionality.  If your app doesn't have critical logic here, it may not be necessary to unit test quite so heavily.  But I'd at least write a few tests to make sure your routes are set up correctly.